# Getting blank page on a Joomla site

Tags: php, joomla

The Joomla 2.5+ version site was working for over year but suddenly it is showing blank page.

Also I am unable to save anything in admin panel. Recently I have also made its beta website with new installation Joomla with different db in beta folder under root directory. I don't really think it has created the problem for the original website.

In the error log under admin panel I found this:

> PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]:
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled
>   or an open_basedir is set in
>   /public_html/plugins/authentication/gmail/gmail.php on line 55

In the error log under home directory I found this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 78 bytes) in
>   /public_html/libraries/gantry/core/utilities/gantrylesscompiler.class.php
>   on line 1594

Comment: Your host is using either `safe_mode` or `open_basedir`. They should both be disabled for the the `curl` functions to work. An alternative would be to disable the gmail authentication plugin.

Comment: And as to the memory error, you can change PHP's memory limits, but this error may hide a deeper issue in memory management.

Comment: Can I reinstall joomla on existing website in order to configure things from zero?

Comment: I would advise against it, as it will remove your generated content. and won't necessarily solve your problem once you restore it. You could try and install a copy it in another location (since this is a test install itself), and gradually enhance it. That said, your error is related to Gantry attempting to compile LESS. You may have changed a LESS file or it is not in Gantry's cache. I suggest that you increase the PHP memory limit (to, say, 128MB) at least for a limited time to allow Gantry to compile and cache the LESS files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but it is still relevant and so I will answer it. Gantry templates typically need a lot of memory (they really are complex), which means that 32 MB of memory allocated to the page is not enough. You will need more. Try creating a `php.ini` file or a `.user.ini` file under the root directory of your Joomla website with the following code:

```
memory_limit = 64M;
```

The above will double the allocated memory per page to 64M, if it doesn't work for you then change it to 128M. Typically, for a low traffic website, you will be on the safe side for up to 256M (unless your website is hit with DoS attack).